# Proof with big-oh

Tags: big-o, proof

Just starting to learn big-oh and asymptotic analysis and I am stuck on this particular proof:

How can we prove 2^n is O(n!)?
Thanks

Comment: Also try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ and maybe a more specific question... (What did you try so far, what are your ideas, etc.)

Comment: Isn't this a <math.stackexchange.com> question?

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, all you have show is that there exists some `C` such that

> 2<sup>n</sup> <= C*n!

for all n greater than some n<sub>0</sub>. This is trivial once you realize that both 2<sup>n</sup> and n! are products with n terms.